# Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query in spring-data

Tags: java, sql, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM t_western_es AS t1 JOIN (SELECT id FROM t_western_es " +
        "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) as t2 ON t1.id=t2.id", nativeQuery = true)
List<WesternEs> findRandom();
```

but i have this error when running the query:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [id] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:241)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:335)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy156.findRandom(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one reason it's often recommended to avoid using `SELECT *` — while duplicate column names are legitimate in a query result as far as MySQL is concerned, the client implementation (JPA in this case) may require that columns of a given result set are unique.

In this case, you could solve the error by only returning columns from one of the joined tables, which would omit the superfluous `id` column from `t2`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t_western_es.* FROM t_western_es AS t1 JOIN (SELECT id FROM t_western_es " +
    "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) as t2 ON t1.id=t2.id", nativeQuery = true)
```

Another solution is to define an alias for the duplicate column to make it distinct:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM t_western_es AS t1 JOIN (SELECT id AS id2 FROM t_western_es " +
    "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) as t2 ON t1.id=t2.id2", nativeQuery = true)
```

(I'm assuming the first table has no column named `id2`.)

A third alternative is to use `JOIN...USING` syntax, which has the effect of eliminating the duplicate column name used for the join:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM t_western_es AS t1 JOIN (SELECT id FROM t_western_es " +
    "ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) as t2 USING (id)", nativeQuery = true)
```